# How do I simplify this Log with a Fraction in it?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

So I have:

$$
\log_2(5x) + \log_2 3 + \frac{\log_2 10}{2}
$$

I understand that when there is addition, and the bases are the same, I can simply multiply what is in the parenthesis. So for the first part, I'd get $\log_2(15x)$. I'm stuck now, because I'm not sure what to do with the third log term, since the entire thing is being divided by two.

Comment: $$a \log_2 b = \log_2(b^a)$$

Comment: @Kushal Bhuyan Your edit changed the question, so I rolled back: the division by two is only on the third term.

Comment: @ClementC. But OP wrote *"the entire log is divided by two, not just what's inside the parenthesis."*. Maybe I misinterpreted.

Comment: He meant, as far as I can tell, "$\frac{\log_2 10}{2}$, not $\log_2\frac{10}{2}$."

Comment: @john Please read through this [nice tutorial and reference on formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), then edit your post to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Okay that's also possible.

Comment: Yes, I meant what Clement C said.

Answer (score 1):

You may write
$$
\log_2(15x)+\frac12 \log_2(10)=\log_2(15x)+\log_2(10^{1/2})=\log_2(15x \cdot10^{1/2}).
$$

Comment: What if I have (5log3(10))/2? It's the same thing, only there's a coefficient to begin with.

Comment: We have $\frac52 \log_3(10)=\log_3(10^{5/2})$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple math like this occasionally trips me.

Comment: @john You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\log_2 10}{2}=\frac{1}{2} \log_2 10  = \log_2 {10^{1/2} = \log_2 \sqrt{10}}$.  Combining this term with the previous terms gives the answer $\log_2(15x \cdot \sqrt{10})$.